# Which bits of SOAP / WS-Security / WS-Addressing / etc do I need to send this message

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-services, ws-security

EDIT:
I think the only bit left to understand is the signing of the message using the [username token profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms824701.aspx).  Any pointers/clues/info on how to implement that would be great.  I have played with the Visual Studio .Net 2003 with WSE 2 and the username token profile sample does this be default- so my fallback is to use that, but prefer to run on Linux, as that is the server we have.  Plus no Mono port of WSE. I get the impression that this is not used much/its deprecated...

I have to talk to a Web Service and have been given the sample below.  I am trying to translate this into English... or at least understand which bits of the WS security specs I need to be looking at to communicate to it.

I am using Ruby/[Savon](http://savon.rubiii.com/) for other WS calls, but it seems to only support basic WSSE, username/passwords.

I can see this message has a **Signature** - but is it signed via an external file/certificate/code or do I have enough details below to do the same signing within my own code.

I dont see any X509 or Cipher entries which seems to imply its not done with such a certificate (in my naive understanding of this), so what is being used to produce the Signature- perhaps just a simple hash of the message?

It also seems to use some sort of digest/message checking as when I try tweaking the sample and resending it, its bounced as invalid - although I guess this might be related to the signature issue...

I dont think Savon supports this and so I am thinking I need to switch to JRuby and use a Java WS library, perhaps [Rampart](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/index.html) with [Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/index.html) or maybe [Spring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/) bits.  Any tips/reccomendation/good tutorials?  I see [this from IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jws4/index.html), but thinking I need something higher level so I can grasp the "big picture"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing"
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">

  <soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action wsu:Id="Id-6762c167-412b-4bf8-8839-518e9bc25da5">
    http://host/path/func</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID wsu:Id="Id-00bb0af8-232d-43a8-adbb-39f230599c56">
    uuid:2005639d-39b8-4df6-bf41-e18741c45291</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:ReplyTo wsu:Id="Id-c53a1dbe-244f-46a9-b656-883f4b06dcfe">
      <wsa:Address>
      http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:To wsu:Id="Id-017877f6-e5a3-43ae-aa2b-4886adb7060c">
    http://host/path/func.asmx</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-1a38d0f9-077f-4e95-991b-fa899a171920">

        <wsu:Created>2011-03-14T15:00:09Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2011-03-14T15:05:09Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
      wsu:Id="SecurityToken-42ae32d2-f6ff-431e-9369-7696b44965e3">
        <wsse:Username>crypteduser</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
        cryptedpass</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce>fLSoqLm9kuOumxy39JRHaw==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2011-03-14T15:00:09Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
          xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" />
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1" />
          <Reference URI="#Id-6762c167-412b-4bf8-8839-518e9bc25da5">

            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>SAYl5o1kh33HteOe0L7G6KIKqWg=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#Id-00bb0af8-232d-43a8-adbb-39f230599c56">

            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>//LMuFkNC1FO1/9A9W7l6o75Y2M=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#Id-c53a1dbe-244f-46a9-b656-883f4b06dcfe">

            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>9pgN7bU48UKi1UTnpOCikOnp2G0=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#Id-017877f6-e5a3-43ae-aa2b-4886adb7060c">

            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>lWZNjtSHfVtiZeOFZAosV868Uos=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#Timestamp-1a38d0f9-077f-4e95-991b-fa899a171920">

            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>H3nYPY6kfIWEIWQhpwaz8VKeQIM=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#Id-f95dfea2-3af8-4e95-8e60-141858db9532">

            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>uRTu+Hzxw+zdaTYgW0z+j35diIQ=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>
        Hdn2wxWhmr450pefMuc41o6GgOA=</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-42ae32d2-f6ff-431e-9369-7696b44965e3"
            ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#UsernameToken" />
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body wsu:Id="Id-f95dfea2-3af8-4e95-8e60-141858db9532">
    <func xmlns="http://host/path/">
      <xml_in>yucky xml inside xml...</xml_in>
    </func>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Many thanks in advance for any tips/pointers you can give.

Regards,
Chris

EDIT

Seems similar to this question... which does use an X509 cert, so perhaps it is needed.
Currently reading the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Signature) for this.

EDIT2

Seems like its this - hopefully the username based option... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms824647.aspx

EDIT3

I think I have most of it [sorted now](https://github.com/kimptoc/savon) - the main thing outstanding is the username digest'ing. How do I do it - where does the signature value come from...

EDIT4

Thinking my best bet is to write a client in .Net and either that will give me enough clues to do it directly in Ruby, or I can wrap it in a simpler version - at least for the short term...

Comment: Welcome to a world of pain; getting OSS SOAP implementations to play nicely with MS is not nearly as easy as it should be.  Check out WSO2, they support this kind of Java/MS SOAP interop...

Comment: Thinking I might have to go that way - but that seems fairly quiet too/unsupported too :(

Comment: Did you ever try to simply use "Add Service Reference" pointing to the WSDL? What happened?

Comment: From Java, I get invalid username token.  Currently trying to working which version of VS I need that will handle the linked code - I guess its VS 2003 with WSE extension...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a full answer, but just a few things I've noticed.

The wsse:SecurityTokenReference refers to this document (in the cryptic sort of soap way): http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0.pdf

I would read through: 3.2 Token Reference

Also, the parent section mentions this formula:

```
Password_Digest = Base64 ( SHA-1 ( nonce + created + password ) )
```

Maybe try something like this for the signature?

```
Password_Digest = Base64 ( SHA-1 ( nonce + created + UsernameToken ) )
```

Comment: Thanks, although I think that relates to the digest'ing of the password text itself - Savon handles that now.  I am looking to digest parts of the wider message using the username/password bits, much as you have done using the certificate.